# Error connecting two raspberry pi with bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

I'm working on a project in which one raspberry pi is going to be a BLE GATT server and the other the client. The first step was testing a normal bluetooth connection via command line but it's not working and I can't figure out why.
Both are raspberry pi 4 model B; the first has raspbian buster with `Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+` while the second has Ubuntu 20.04 server with `Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1036-raspi`.

Using `bluetoothctl`, on the first (the slave) I set `agent on` `discoverable on` and `pairable on` while on the second I use `scan on`. The second raspberry finds the other MAC address so I continue with `pair DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90`. The pairing *seems* to be successful but it doesn't even ask for the passcode:

slave RPI output:

```
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 Discoverable: yes
[NEW] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 ubuntu
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0535
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 Connected: no
```

master RPI output:

```
Attempting to pair with DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 UUIDs: 0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 Connected: no
```

ubuntu is the name of the other RPI and its MAC is DC:A6:32:FD:47:E0 as you can see from the output. During the pairing the connection is established for few seconds and then disconnects. When I try to connect with `connect DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90` from the master basically the same happens:

```
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:2C:D4:90 Connected: no
```

using bluetoothctl with sudo and trusting the devices doesn't seem to help.

edit: by using `default-agent` on both devices, I was asked to confirm the pin but the connection still fails

Comment: The connection is not "failing". The client is connecting to the peripheral and not finding any supported services that it understands so disconnects. The best approach is to develop just one end of the Bluetooth link at a time. At the other end of the link use an app that can be the client (e.g. [nRF connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile)) or the peripheral (e.g [BLE Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral))

Comment: @ukBaz I see, but looking online for solutions I found different posts showing that after the connection the name of the device connected stays written in the bluetoothctl command line, so it seems that it stays connected after the command and  it doesn't that they have any ble service up. Could it be another setting like the agent configuration or I'm just assuming wrong?

Comment: To look for detailed debug information you need to have `sudo btmon` running and review the output from that. However, given the information you have shared, the most likely issue if the client disconnects after `ServicesResolved; Yes` happens, is that there is not a service that the client understands (BLE or Classic) on the server/peripheral.